# how to define a regular expression in boost?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-regex

I have a section in file:

```
[Source]

[Source.Ia32]


[Source.Ia64]
```

I have created the expression as:

const boost::regex source_line_pattern ("(Sources)(.*?)");

Now, I am trying to match the string, but I am not able to match; it is always returning 0.

```
if (boost::regex_match ( sToken, source_line_pattern ) )
  return TRUE;
```

Please note that sToken value is [Source]. [Source.Ia32]... and so on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems with your code.  First, the
regular expression you give contains the literal string
`"Sources"`, and not `"Source"`, which is what you seem to be
trying to match.  The second is that `boost::regex_match` is
bound: it must match the entire string.  What you seem to want
is `boost::regex_search`.  Depending on what you are doing,
however, it might be better to try to match the entire string:
`"\\[Source(?:\\.(\\w+))?\\]\\s*"`. Which provides for capture of
the trailing part, if present (but not the leading
`"Source"`---no point, in general, in capturing something that is
a constant).

Note too that the sequence `".*?"` is very dubious.  Normally,
I would expect the regular expression parser to fail if
a (non-escaped) `'*'` is followed by a `'?'`.

Comment: `.*?` means non-greedy repeat in Perl regex syntax, which is the default in `boost::regex`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax_perl.html

Comment: I have added the regular expression "\\[Source(?:\.(\\w+))?\\]\\s*" but it is still returning 0.

Comment: @svk Ah.  I didn't look it up, and just interpreted it as a `*` followed by a `?`, not as a single token `*?`.

Comment: @user1553605 From the string you quote, it doesn't look like you're escaping all of the `'\\'` correctly.  (I missed one myself in my original posting---I've fixed that now.)  In this particular case, all of the `'\\'` are for `boost::regex`,  so all need to be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `boost::regex_match` only returns true if the entire input string is matched by the regex.  So the '[' and ']' are not matched by your current regex, and it will fail.

Your options are either to use `boost::regex_search`, which will search for a substring of the input that matches your regex, or modify your regex to accept the entire string being passed in.